`free(): invalid next size (normal)` after loading some frames of some videos using ffmpeg libs
here is the function:
uint8_t *load_first_frame(const char *file_path, AVFrame **frame)
{
    int ret;
    AVFormatContext *format_ctx = NULL;
    if ((ret = avformat_open_input(&format_ctx, file_path, NULL, NULL)) < 0) {
        eprintf("could not open input file\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    if ((ret = avformat_find_stream_info(format_ctx, NULL)) < 0) {
        eprintf("could not find stream info\n");
        avformat_close_input(&format_ctx);
        return NULL;
    }

    int stream_idx = -1;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < format_ctx->nb_streams; i++) {
        if (format_ctx->streams[i]->codecpar->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) {
            stream_idx = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (stream_idx == -1) {
        eprintf("could not find video stream\n");
        avformat_close_input(&format_ctx);
        return NULL;
    }

    AVCodecParameters *codec_par = format_ctx->streams[stream_idx]->codecpar;
    const AVCodec *codec = avcodec_find_decoder(codec_par->codec_id);
    if (!codec) {
        eprintf("could not find decoder\n");
        avformat_close_input(&format_ctx);
        return NULL;
    }

    AVCodecContext *codec_ctx = avcodec_alloc_context3(codec);
    if ((ret = avcodec_parameters_to_context(codec_ctx, codec_par)) < 0) {
        eprintf("could not copy codec parameters to context\n");
        avformat_close_input(&format_ctx);
        avcodec_free_context(&codec_ctx);
        return NULL;
    }

    if ((ret = avcodec_open2(codec_ctx, codec, NULL)) < 0) {
        eprintf("could not open codec\n");
        avformat_close_input(&format_ctx);
        avcodec_free_context(&codec_ctx);
        return NULL;
    }

    AVPacket *packet = av_packet_alloc();
    uint8_t *rgb_buffer = NULL;
    while (av_read_frame(format_ctx, packet) >= 0) {
        if (packet->stream_index != stream_idx) {
            av_packet_unref(packet);
            continue;
        }

        if (avcodec_send_packet(codec_ctx, packet) != 0) {
            av_packet_unref(packet);
            continue;
        }

        ret = avcodec_receive_frame(codec_ctx, *frame);
        if (ret == AVERROR(EAGAIN) || ret == AVERROR_EOF) {
            av_packet_unref(packet);
            continue;
        } else if (ret < 0) {
            eprintf("error receiving frame: %d\n", ret);
            av_packet_unref(packet);
            av_packet_free(&packet);
            avformat_close_input(&format_ctx);
            avcodec_free_context(&codec_ctx);
            return NULL;
        }

        struct SwsContext *sws_ctx = sws_getContext(
            (*frame)->width, (*frame)->height, codec_ctx->pix_fmt,
            (*frame)->width, (*frame)->height, AV_PIX_FMT_RGB24,
            SWS_BILINEAR, NULL, NULL, NULL
        );

        if (!sws_ctx) {
            eprintf("failed to create SwsContext\n");
            av_packet_unref(packet);
            av_packet_free(&packet);
            av_frame_free(frame);
            avformat_close_input(&format_ctx);
            avcodec_free_context(&codec_ctx);
            return NULL;
        }

        int rgb_buffer_size = av_image_get_buffer_size(AV_PIX_FMT_RGB24, (*frame)->width, (*frame)->height, 1);
        if (rgb_buffer_size < 0) {
            eprintf("could not get buffer size\n");
            sws_freeContext(sws_ctx);
            av_packet_unref(packet);
            av_packet_free(&packet);
            av_frame_free(frame);
            avformat_close_input(&format_ctx);
            avcodec_free_context(&codec_ctx);
            return NULL;
        }

        rgb_buffer = (uint8_t *) malloc(rgb_buffer_size);
        if (rgb_buffer == NULL) {
            eprintf("failed to allocate RGB buffer\n");
            sws_freeContext(sws_ctx);
            av_packet_unref(packet);
            av_packet_free(&packet);
            avformat_close_input(&format_ctx);
            av_frame_free(frame);
            avcodec_free_context(&codec_ctx);
            return NULL;
        }

        uint8_t *dst[4] = {rgb_buffer, NULL, NULL, NULL};
        int dst_linesize[4] = {0};
        av_image_fill_linesizes(dst_linesize, AV_PIX_FMT_RGB24, (*frame)->width);

        sws_scale(sws_ctx,
                            (const uint8_t *const *)(*frame)->data,
                            (*frame)->linesize,
                            0,
                            (*frame)->height,
                            dst,
                            dst_linesize);

        sws_freeContext(sws_ctx);
        av_packet_unref(packet);
        break;
    }

    av_packet_unref(packet);
    av_packet_free(&packet);
    avformat_close_input(&format_ctx);
    avcodec_free_context(&codec_ctx);

    return rgb_buffer;
}

It loads up first frames of mp4s. The problem is that it works only first 7 times, and then, on 8th call of the showed function malloc(): corrupted top size happens. Specifically when call avcodec_send_packet in the while loop. Executing program using valgrind outputs that:
==21777== Invalid write of size 8
==21777==    at 0x7426956: ??? (in /usr/lib/libswscale.so.8.1.100)
==21777==    by 0x18497CBF: ???
==21777==    by 0x35E3AD3F: ???
==21777==  Address 0x37f563f0 is 0 bytes after a block of size 2,194,560 alloc'd
==21777==    at 0x48447A8: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:446)
==21777==    by 0x1113CB: load_first_frame (main.c:503)
==21777==    by 0x111995: draw_preview (main.c:605)
==21777==    by 0x111E7F: render_files (main.c:672)
==21777==    by 0x11209E: main (main.c:704)
==21777==
==21777== Invalid write of size 8
==21777==    at 0x742695B: ??? (in /usr/lib/libswscale.so.8.1.100)
==21777==    by 0x18497CBF: ???
==21777==    by 0x35E3AD3F: ???
==21777==  Address 0x37f563f8 is 8 bytes after a block of size 2,194,560 alloc'd
==21777==    at 0x48447A8: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:446)
==21777==    by 0x1113CB: load_first_frame (main.c:503)
==21777==    by 0x111995: draw_preview (main.c:605)
==21777==    by 0x111E7F: render_files (main.c:672)
==21777==    by 0x11209E: main (main.c:704)
==21777==
==21777== Invalid write of size 8
==21777==    at 0x7426956: ??? (in /usr/lib/libswscale.so.8.1.100)
==21777==    by 0x183FE37F: ???
==21777==    by 0x185D16FF: ???
==21777==  Address 0x389b94e0 is 0 bytes after a block of size 943,200 alloc'd
==21777==    at 0x48447A8: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:446)
==21777==    by 0x1113CB: load_first_frame (main.c:503)
==21777==    by 0x111995: draw_preview (main.c:605)
==21777==    by 0x111E7F: render_files (main.c:672)
==21777==    by 0x11209E: main (main.c:704)

The 503th line is: rgb_buffer = (uint8_t *) malloc(rgb_buffer_size);.
Apparently, I double freed something somewhere, but I can't see where exactly. AVFrame **frame that is passed to the function is allocated and freed properly every time using av_frame_alloc and av_frame_free. The mp4 file from file_path is always just a normal video, and it always exists.
I've tried loading up different mp4 files, the crash happens every time exactly on 8th call of the function

Perhaps you write out of bounds somewhere? Those Invalid write of size 8 messages would indicate that. And that the call-stack can't be printed could indicate a stack error.

Does AV_PIX_FMT_RGB24 have a linesize alignment requirement that's larger than 1?

Note that load_first_frame is only the function responsible for allocating the chunk of memory, not the one where the invalid write out of bounds happens. You may be using the returned chunk incorrectly and passing it around in the wrong way.

There's the classic malloc bug of casting the result here rgb_buffer = (uint8_t *) malloc(rgb_buffer_size); but forgetting to include stdlib.h, which I don't see anywhere in the posted code. Should only be an issue in C89 though or otherwise the compiler would whine about it.

Not related to the error, but wouldn't it be better to use av_image_alloc instead of malloc?

Can you install a debuginfo package for libswscale.so?

It would also help if you told us which Version of Valgrind, what OS, what CPU and what compiler you are using.
